# CSS Image Effects

Tags: css, image

I was wondering that how I can make page with 2 images and when someone puts mouse over them the image will get blurry and it will show some text over it?

I think this is somehow made with CSS but I can't figure it out how??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several way to create this, one is to use 2 images, one by default another on hover from css, the text can stand inside the div holding the image. If it is not responsive, it will look something like this:

```css
.image{
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
 }
 .image:after{
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      content: ' ';
      background-image: url(http://raumrot.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/msp_0706_7933.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      display: block;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
}
.image:hover:after {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
.text {
  visibility: hidden;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.image:hover .text {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <span class="text">Some Here</span>
</div>
```

I hope this gives an idea, but something like this.

Answer (score 2):

For starters:

```css
div > img {
  position: absolute;
}
div > p {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-in;
  opacity:0;
}
div > img:hover {
  filter: blur(2px);
}
div > img:hover + p {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRVfOu73XA2Ebqxqa5pKzp_90m6aSIx1EcNu9s3axKCn_YfqDGcnA" />
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

P.S: Really, you need to surf this thing called **GOOGLE**, its awesome!!! <3

Comment: Your irony doesn't help. Maybe you can start suggesting the SO help page. Then something related to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make some research about css `blur` and `position:absolute` for the text you want to show/hide on `mouseover`. Start with those things, you will figure it out...